# Understading elasticsearch document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm reading [elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_document_oriented.html) and have some troubles with understanding the concept of document and indexing.

> Elasticsearch is document oriented, meaning that it stores entire
>   objects or documents.

The example they provide it this:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/megacorp/empolyee/3/?pretty" -d '                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                

    "first_name": "Douglas",
    "last_name": "Fir",
    "age": 35,
    "about": "I like to build cabinets",
    "interest": ["forestry"]
}
'
```

As far as I understood, `megacorp` is the index here. But what is the document? Is the employee with the number `3` is a document? Or all employees, stored by path `megacorp/employee` form a single document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/megacorp/employee/3/?pretty" -d '                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                

    "first_name": "Douglas",
    "last_name": "Fir",
    "age": 35,
    "about": "I like to build cabinets",
    "interest": ["forestry"]
}'
```

- `megacorp` is the index
- `employee` is the mapping type (i.e. the definition of all employee fields and their types)
- `3` is the ID of the employee
- `{"first_name": "Douglas", ..., "interest": ["forestry"]}` is the document containing all the fields of employee `3`

Basically, if we draw a parallel to a conventional RDBMS:

- `megacorp` would be the database name
- `employee` would be the database table containing all employee records (i.e. the employee schema)
- `3` would be the primary key of the employee record
- `{"first_name": "Douglas", ..., "interest": ["forestry"]}` would be the record containing all the fields of employee `3`